# Website is broken in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I am new to html5, html and JavaScript. My website http://www.countrybait.com/ is looking perfect in Chrome and IE9 but its broken in IE8. Problem is my client has a IE8 and when I showed him it was bad looking. I tried alot to fix this but couldn't able to fix and don't know what to do to fix and atleast get a clean view in IE8. So please seniors help me. Waiting for your positive help.

Answer (score 2):

There are many differences between the browsers you mentioned. Each one renders css a little bit differently, especially IE8. IE9 has a developer tools set (press F12 or look under Tools icon). There you can choose which browser mode you would like to see and it should render the page according to that setting. You can then see what items are causing the layout issue and make the necessary changes.

I always build to Chrome or Firefox, then go back and make it work in IE.

Depending on your site, it might take a bit to get everything working in IE8. There is not a simple fix.

Answer (score 2):

I tried turning on "Compatibility Mode" in IE8, and it makes most things be in roughly the right position (notable exceptions are the top menu navigation and the main text content).

So one strategy you might like to employ is to try to get it to look good in IE7 / IE8 Compatibility Mode, then you can add a meta tag like:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

to your page to force IE to run in compatibility mode. Note you may need to surround this with IE conditional comments to make sure it doesn't run in IE9, which looks fine.

e.g.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Can you please explain in little more detail please. I am sorry i am too dump to understand. Please help me to fix this issue. Waiting for your response.

Comment: @Imran. I'd love to help, but unfortunately learning how to make sites cross-browser compatible is something that comes with practice and experience. Your best bet is to learn to use the various Developer Tools in the browsers (Firebug in Firefox, Developer Tools in IE and Chrome) to debug why things display differently.

Answer (score 0):

Oh the newbie pain of IE, hurts dont it?

I realize that your are new to this kind of thing but see how quickly you can get up to speed with Sass/Compass. Compass comes with a lot of helper shortcodes and cross browser handeling. Its the new hotness and the real pro's use it (like myself :D )

Sass = shorthand css w/ nesting (so clutch), variables (nice and dynamic), mixins (templates)

Compass = framework to avoid cross browser issues and css prefixes, and some other cool junk.

Do it, seriously... I wish somebody told me to sooner.

Comment: Any other help seniors...I am really a new and all the things you guys are sharing with me are very difficult for me to handle. I tried but because I am not expert, it went more wrong. :(

Comment: Downvoted, cause although your recommendations are nice in general, they likely doesn't help to op -- too broad

Comment: I don't think that garners a downvote. I preface it with "I realize you are new to this kind of thing". I at least provide a positive direction. A downvote is assuming its misinformation, the wrong advice entirely, or irrelevant. Could you bring it back up? Don't want my rep killed when just having joined.